# SEF URL Problem in Joomla1.5

Tags: url, joomla, sef

My joomla site url is: http://www.cessnatrader.com. I am using SEF URL for this site. The SEF URL is not working in the main menu(in top). But it is working fine for other places(other links, footer menu). I don't know what the problem is. I did all the things for enabling SEF URL in joomla. But it is not working in one place(main menu). What should I do?

Note: I am using "Mosets tree" component in this site.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing all of your menu items and then add them again. One thing I've noticed when implementing SEF URLs in Joomla was that any link I created before I turned on SEF wouldn't be converted. Delete and rebuild the link from scratch.